# Variation of Putnam Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help to evaluate the integral of $\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2 + 1}$ from $0$ to $1.$

The Putnam exam once had the same problem but with $\ln (x+1).$ Feynman's technique didn't help me once that $+1$ was gone.

What should I do?

Comment: $-G$ where $G$ is Catalan's constant.  So: there is no nice trick as there was in the actual Putnam problem. Hint: $$\int_0^1 x^n\ln(x)\;dx = -(n+1)^{-2}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\ln{\left(x\right)}}{1+x^2}dx}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^n\int_{0}^{1}{\ln{\left(x\right)}x^{2n}dx}&\buildrel{{IBP}}\over{\overbrace{=}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^n\left[{\underbrace{\frac{x^{2n+1}\ln{\left(x\right)}}{2n+1}}_{0}}-\frac{x^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)^2}\right]_0^1\\&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(2n+1\right)^2}=-G\end{align}$$

G stands for Catalan’s Constant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Integration by parts with $f=\ln(x)$ and $g'=1/(x^2+1)$ $$\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)}{x^2+1}dx=\left[\ln \left(x\right)\arctan \left(x\right)-\int \frac{\arctan \left(x\right)}{x}dx\right]^1_0$$
You must consider that the 2nd integral is not elementary.
$$\int \frac{\arctan \left(x\right)}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2}i\left(\text{Li}_2\left(-ix\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(ix\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

With regard to the antiderivative, use partial fraction decomposition and write
$$\frac 1 {x^2+1}=\frac 1 {(x+i)(x-i)}=\frac i 2 \left(\frac 1 {x+i}-\frac 1 {x-i }\right)$$ and you face two integrals
$$I=\int \frac {\log(x)}{x+a}\,dx=\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{x}{a}\right)+\log (x) \log \left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)$$ which make
$$J(x)=\int\frac {\log(x)} {x^2+1}=\log (x) \tan ^{-1}(x)+\frac{i}{2} \left(\text{Li}_2(i x)-\text{Li}_2(-i x)\right)$$ and
$$J(1)-J(0)=-C$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^nx}{1+x^2}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\int_0^1x^{2k}\ln^nx\ dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left[\frac{(-1)^{n}n!}{(2k+1)^{n+1}}\right]$$

$$=(-1)^nn!\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^{n+1}}=(-1)^nn!\beta(n+1)$$

where [$\beta(n+1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function?fbclid=IwAR2JKUjyn8sG4wMdUfeT3JyJLpw7C-aanbnwRYbIZ0k9QYwA3Hz1_0OsQhU) is the Dirichlet beta function.

---

To calculate $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$ just set $\frac{1-x}{1+x}=y$, you will have a symmetry and the answer will be extracted right away.